# How to read blob data in Python

Tags: python, string, blob, apex, rest

From Salesforce File, I want to read the file and get the content between some text and store it in the Custom object record field.
For this, I have created an external API(python script deployed to heroku) where I am sending the file content as blob(basically the content of the file is Blob in Salesforce
).
Now I want to read the file and get the text. But I was not able to read the blob data.
If I convert the blob to string in SF while posting and decode it in python also doesn't work. Please give some inputs on this. I am new to python.

my python code :

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import base64
import blob
  
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get/record/', methods=['GET', 'POST','DELETE', 'PATCH'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("===inside===")
        payload_list = request.get_json(force=True)           
        print("====next line payload_list ===")
        print(blob(payload_list["BlobData"])
        # responseStr = str(payload_list["BlobData"])
        # print("===decodedata===")
        # print(base64.b64decode(responseStr))
  return "sucesss"
```

Salesforce Rest Code:

```
List<ContentVersion> cv = [SELECT ContentDocumentId,VersionData from ContentVersion
                            where ContentDocumentId = 'xxxxxxxxxx' order by CreatedDate DESC];
String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cv[0].versiondata);
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://realpyth.herokuapp.com/get/fileService/');
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setBody('{"BlobData":"'+cv[0].versiondata+'"}'); // Send the data as Blob
//request.setBody('{"BlobData":"'+bodyEncoded+'"}'); // Convert the blob data and send as String
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
System.debug('=======' +response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getBody());
} else {
System.debug('====response==='+response.getBody());
}
```